# R: package vignette not built

Tags: r, r-package, vignette

#### Problem

I created a small internal package for my company. To describe hot to use it, I wrote a vignette. But for some reason, the vignette is not built when I hit *Install and Restart* in RStudio.

#### Further Information

- I use roxygen for the package documentation
- Interestingly, the output from *Install and Restart* says that it is installed:

  ```
  ==> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

  Updating DataReportR documentation
  Loading DataReportR
  Documentation completed

  ==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source DataReportR

  * installing to library 'C:/Program Files/R/library'
  * installing *source* package 'DataReportR' ...
  ** R
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
  ** building package indices
  ** installing vignettes
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded
  * DONE (DataReportR)
  ```
- `devtools::build_vignettes()` returns `NULL` even though the lines

  ```
  Suggests: knitr, rmarkdown
  VignetteBuilder: knitr
  ```

  are included in the DESCRIPTION.
- The YAML header of the vignette looks like this:

  ```
  ---
  title: "My title"
  output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
  vignette: >
    %\VignetteIndexEntry{Generate LaTeX tables for Data Reports}
    %\VignetteEngine{rmarkdown::render}
    %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  ---
  ```
- I also tried to force building the vignette by `devtools::build(vignettes = TRUE)` but nothing changed.

### EDIT (changed YAML header):

When I change `%\VignetteEngine{rmarkdown::render}` to `%\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}` in the vignette's YAML header, `devtools::build_vignettes()` works and places the built vignette in `/inst/doc/`.

However, when I *Check* the package in RStudio, the check fails at this position:

```
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: create_var_details, create_var_overview
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

Both `create_var_details` and `create_var_overview` are exported functions. Here an example:

```
... 
#' @export
#' 
    create_var_details <- function(...
...
```

With the old header, the checks were fine.

Comment: Can you try writing `%\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}` instead of  `%\VignetteEngine{rmarkdown::render}`? I created an small package also time ago and that is the unique difference I have.

Comment: @R18: This results in an error during `devtools::check()`: 
`** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: create_var_details, create_var_overview`. But these functions are exported... Also, I use `%\VignetteEngine{rmarkdown::render}` in another project without problems.

Comment: Are `create_var_details` and `create_var_overview` functions or objects in your code?

Comment: exported functions. From the NAMESPACE:
`# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(create_var_details)
export(create_var_overview)`

Comment: I remember once, when I deleted the files that `roxygen2`generates and running again the code it worked and the files were generated again. May be is not the case, . . .

Comment: Already tried that, but did not help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that R did not find `pandoc`. Thus, I added the `pandoc` path to the `PATH` environment variable. I also changed the vignette enginge to `%\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}` as suggested in the comments by @R18.

Now the vignette is properly built when I click on *Install and Restart* in RStudio.

However, checking the package still does not work. See my **EDIT** to the question. But this in another question: [R package: Adding a vignette causes 'undefined exports'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233040/r-package-adding-a-vignette-causes-undefined-exports?noredirect=1#comment85473656_49233040)